# Top panel icons overwitten by nonsense

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, panel, application-switcher

I can't think of anything better to describe what's happening. My top panel looks now like this:

[image]

It is fully functional though and goes back to 'normal' when I click on each one of the icons. It goes back to some more nonsense when I use the Static Application Switcher to alt-tab.